# Multiple returns from api call (json)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

i have a problem since i want to get multiple data from a single api call
How can i return more than one value from it?
I'm running this function, it create the correct logs, but not the return part.

```
function getParts(axieID) {
  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(`https://api.axie.technology/getaxies/${axieID}`);
  const data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

  try {
    Logger.log(data.class)
    Logger.log(data.parts[1].name)
    return {
      total: data.class
    }, {
      total1: data.parts[1].name
    };
  } catch (e) {
    Logger.log(e)
    return {
      total: 'error',
      total1: 'error'
    }
  }
}
```

EDIT

```
var {total} = getParts(axieID);
  if (total != 'error') {
  sh3.getRange('J'+counter).setValue(total);
  }
  Utilities.sleep(700)
  }
  var {total1} = getParts(axieID);
  if (total1 != 'error') {
  sh3.getRange('K'+counter).setValue(total1);
  }
  Utilities.sleep(700)
```

SOLUTION (total changed with classe, and total1 changed with orecchie):

```
function getParts(axieID) {
const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(`https://api.axie.technology/getaxies/${axieID}`);
const data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

try {
  Logger.log(data.class)
  Logger.log(data.parts[1].name)
  return {classe : data.class, orecchie : data.parts[1].name};
}
catch (e) { 
           Logger.log(e)
           return {
               classe: 'error', orecchie: 'error'
           }
   }
}

  var {classe,orecchie} = getParts(axieID);
  if (classe != 'error') {
  sh3.getRange('J'+counter).setValue(classe);
  }
  if (orecchie != 'error') {
  sh3.getRange('K'+counter).setValue(orecchie);
  }
  Utilities.sleep(700)
  }
```

Comment: Just look at your own catch block to see how to do this...

Comment: As for your follow up question: `const { total, total1 } = getParts(axieID);` Although even if you don't know about this syntax, you could still do `const result = getParts(axieID);` then simply access `result.total` and `result.total1`

Answer (score 1):

Approach # 1:

Return an object which includes both properties like that and easily use them by calling getParts(id).total or getParts(id).total1 :

```
function getParts(axieID) {
const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(`https://api.axie.technology/getaxies/${axieID}`);
const data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

try {
  Logger.log(data.class)
  Logger.log(data.parts[1].name)
  return {total : data.class, total1 : data.parts[1].name};
}
catch (e) { 
           Logger.log(e)
           return {
               total: 'error', total1: 'error'
           }
   }
}
```

Approach # 2:
By returning array

```
function getParts(axieID) {
const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(`https://api.axie.technology/getaxies/${axieID}`);
const data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

try {
  Logger.log(data.class)
  Logger.log(data.parts[1].name);
  let total=data.class;
  let total1=data.parts[1].name;
  return [total, total1];
}
catch (e) { 
           Logger.log(e)
           return {
               total: 'error', total1: 'error'
           }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou! using the first one, i have some problems declaring the value to set later (i edited the first post). In this i was i can only set the first (total) value.

Comment: You are calling function 2 times:
call 1 time only by using const {total,total1}=getParts(axieID)

Comment: Mhhh the second approach have some issues. It doesn't write anything.

Comment: PERFECT! It works with approach #1 :)

Comment: Second approach returns array which you can get from:
const value=getParts(axieID);
You can access total value by accessing value[0] (0th index) and similarly total1 value by accessing value[1]